# Задача со строками на C/C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Дано 2 предложения (1е оканчивается точкой; предложения разделены пробелом). Необходимо поменять предложения местами.

Желательно сделать на массивах, без лишних C++ функций.

Посмотрите плз, я на VS 2010 написал. Я сделал, но у меня не работает (выдает различного рода ошибки, полагаю проблемы с компилятором):

```
#include<windows.h> // Вызов библиотеки для смены кодировки
#include<iostream> // Вызов библиотеки для задержки экрана
#include<stdio.h>

#define SZ 70

void main (void)
{
  SetConsoleOutputCP(1251); // Смена кодировки на "windows-1251"

  FILE *In;
  In = fopen("In.txt", "r"); // в файле 2 предложения

  char s[SZ];
  int end, i;

  // ввод строки из файла в массив s
  for(i = 0; i < SZ; i++){
    fscanf(In, "%c", s[i]);
  }
  fclose(In);

  // определение конца 1го предложения
  for(i = 0; i < SZ; i++){
    if (s[i] == '.'){
      end = i;
      break;
    }
  }

  // вывод 2го предложения
  for(i = end + 2; i < SZ; i++){
    printf("%c", s[i]);
  }
  printf(" ");

  // вывод 1го предложения
  for(i = 0; i <= end; i++){
    printf("%c", s[i]);
  }

  system("pause");
}
```

После запуска программы вылетает ошибка:

*Необработанное исключение в "0x5ba8de8f (msvcr100d.dll)" в "it_lab_6.exe": 0xC0000005: Нарушение прав доступа при записи "0xffffffcc".*

с указанием на исходник файла input.c:

```
#ifndef _UNICODE
  *(char *)pointer = (char)ch;
  pointer = (char *)pointer + 1;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ПЛАН "A"

1. Определяем размер файла. Можно с помощь fseek.
2. Выделяем место под буфер, куда все считаем.
3. Используем fread и считываем все за раз.
4. Идем по массиву, пока не встретим '.'. Все что за точкой - копируем в отдельный массив и зануляем в исходном.

ПЛАН "Б"

В цикле считываем строчки из файла с помощью fgets. Эта функция считывает строго ОДНУ строчку. Ну, а дальше проблем нет :-)

Comment: fread'ом в массив или в строковую переменную? Если последняя, то как в массив разобрать строку?

Comment: Строка - массив char'ов. Так что без разницы. Просто нужно учесть, что fread не будет добавлять символ окончания строки '\0', а выдаст данные как они есть в файле. fgets же делает "настоящую" 0-terminated строку. Читайте справку.

Answer (score 3):

```
#define n 70
```

поменяйте на SZ 70

```
for(i = 0;(i<n)&&(s[i]!=' '); i++);
end=i;
```

Возможно лучше считать строку

```
fscanf(In, "%s", s);
```

попробуйте использовать getch() вместо паузы из библиотеки conio.h

Comment: Добавлю.
Да, и у вас надо проверять ни один символ пробела " ", а два - точка-пробел ". ".
По описанию, `fscanf(In, "%s", s);`, извлекает только часть последовательности символов до пробела, табуляции или новой строки.
И вот это, действительно, стоило бы убрать `(char)" "`, заменив на одинарные кавычки:).

Comment: Да правда там нужен while(!eof) и конкатинация

Comment: Там кстати у меня не символ пробела должен быть, а точка (ошибся).

Если считать строку, то как его потом разбить в массив? (со строками насколько я помню, тоже выскакивает подобная ошибка)

С паузой все нормаль в остальных проектах.

P.S. Если кому не сложно, проверьте плз мой код у себя на VS. А то, я полагаю, у меня компилятор сдох.

Comment: попробуйте паузу заменить и дефайн, проверьте хватает ли у вас символов в файле.

Comment: Да, попробовал. Все также с ошибкой. Символов достаточно.

Пробовал убрать части кода - ошибка сводится к чтению из файла (указание на input.c char) - о чем это говорит?

Comment: попробуйте уменьшить n до 20,
судя по всему ошибка чтения символа,
попробуйте еще убрать переключение кодировок

Comment: с "SZ 70" тоже работает, а переключении кодировки убрал т.к. вывожу в файл. Надо было амперсант просто поставить.

Comment: А да точно) Что-то я пропустил это)